# A case where javascript prototype property is undefined. Would like to find out the reason

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var Person = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};
console.log("1 " + typeof(Person.prototype)) //"object" - prototype is a property of a first class functional object

Person.prototype.sayhi = function(){console.log("hi")};

var john = new Person();

console.log("2 "+typeof(Person.sayhi)) // "undefined"
console.log("3 "+typeof(john.sayhi))// "function"
```

I am trying to get a better understanding of javascript prototype.

I wonder why case 2 returns undefined, while case 3 returns "object" as it should.

I read up on other posts but can't seem to find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like a constructor function simply isn't an instance/clone of its own prototype.

Comment: `typeof john.sayhi` is `function`!

Comment: Thanks Bergi. It was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @WilsonWang Are there any questions remaining, BLSully and I have explained it thoroughly from what we can tell. It's unclear why you think `Person.sayhi` should be pointing to same thing as `Person.prototype.sayhi` Please comment on one of our answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions attached to the prototype (`Person.prototype`) are not accessible from a constructor (`Person`), that is `Person.sayhi` is not trying to access the prototype at all.

When you call a constructor (say `var p = new Person()`), `Person.prototype` is attached to the prototype chain of the created object (`p`), that's why you can call `p.sayhi()`. However, `sayhi` is never attached to the constructor

Comment: Thanks that answered my question. I was under the wrong assumption that Person.prototype.sayhi would attach sayhi() directly to Person (i.e Person.sayhi() )

Answer (score 0):

Because your "2" console.log isn't looking at the prototype:

```
Person.sayHi = function() { console.log('I am not in an instance'); }
console.log(typeof(Person.sayHi)); //"function"
var john = new Person();
console.log(typeof(john.sayHi)); //"undefined"
```

is different than:

```
Person.prototype.sayHi = function() { console.log('Hi'); }
console.log(typeof(Person.sayHi)); //"undefined"
console.log(typeof(Person.prototype.sayHi)); //"function"
var john = new Person();
console.log(typeof(john.sayHi)); //"function"
```

sort of the difference between static and instance methods in c#/java